# Loop thru a list and stop when the first string is found

Tags: python

I have a list and I want to extract to another list the data that exist between top_row and bottom_row.
I know the top_row and also that the bottom_row corresponds to data[0] = last integer data (next row is made of strings, but there are also rows with integers which I'm not interested).

I've tried several things, but w/o success:

```
for row,data in enumerate(fileData):
    if row > row_elements: #top_row
        try:
            n = int(data[0])
            aux = True
        except:
            n = 0
        while aux: #until it finds the bottom_row
            elements.append(data)
```

The problem is that it never iterates the second row, if I replace while with if I get all rows which the first column is an integer.

fileData is like:

```
*Element, type=B31H
  1,   1,   2
  2,   2,   3
  .
  .
  .
 359, 374, 375
 360, 375, 376
*Elset, elset=PART-1-1_LEDGER-1-LIN-1-2-RAD-2__PICKEDSET2, generate
```

I'm only interested in rows with first column values equal to 1 to 360.

Many thanks!

Comment: try changing `while aux` to `if aux`, if I understand your code correctly, that should works.

Comment: That works, but the file has multiple strings and integer values, and I'm only interested in the integer values contained in a specific area...

Comment: What is the structure of `data` like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no exception is thrown in the `try` part, then you basically end up with an endless loop, given that `aux` will always be `True`.

I’m not perfectly sure what you are doing in your code, given the way the data looks isn’t clear and some things are not used (like `n`?), but in general, you can stop a running loop (both `for` and `while` loops) with the `break` statement:

```
for row, data in enumerate(fileData):
    if conditionToAbortTheLoop:
        break
```

So in your case, I would guess something like this would work:

```
for row, data in enumerate(fileData):
    if row > row_elements: # below `top_row`
        try:
            int(data[0])
        except ValueError:
            break # not an int value, `bottom_row` found

        # if we get here, we’re between the top- and bottom row.
        elements.append(data)
```

Comment: Accepted your answer because it's the best!

Answer (score 4):

The code you've posted is confusing.  For example, "aux" is a poorly-named variable.  And the loop really wants to start with a specific element of the input, but it loops over everything  until it finds the iteration it wants, turning what might be a constant-time operation into a linear one.  Let's try rewriting it:

```
for record in fileData[row_elements:]: # skip first row_elements (might need +1?)
    try:
        int(record[0])
    except ValueError:
        break # found bottow_row, stop iterating
    elements.append(record)
```

Comment: +1 for the loop start; `int()` raises a `ValueError` if it fails  though, not a `TypeError`.

Comment: It gives the following error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '*Elset', it seems it does not stop in the last integer row...

Answer (score 1):

Will this work?

```
for row, data in enumerate(fileData):
    if row > row_elements: #top_row
        try:
            n = int(data[0])
            elements.append(data)
        except ValueError:
            continue
```

Or what about:

```
elements = [int(data[0]) for data in fileData if data[0].isdigit()]
```

By the way, if you care to follow the convention of most `python` code, you can rename `fileData` to `file_data`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a generator:

```
def isInteger(testInput):
    try: 
        int(testInput)
        return True
    except ValueError: return False

def integersOnly(fileData):
    element = fileData.next()
    while isInteger(element):
        yield element
        element = fileData.next()
```